# Is it possible to stage some changes to a file in Visual Studio (Community) with Git SVC like it is with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2022

I am working with Visual Studio 2022RC and Git for version control. I am obligated to use Visual Studio for some projects for a variety of reasons. I have set my Git diff tool and merge tool to be Visual Studio.

Sometimes I find myself with multiple changes to a single file that I would like to break up and explain, or I want to commit a files separately but not without the corresponding change to the Visual Studio project file.

In Visual Studio Code I can open the *diff* and select lines and 'stage selected range' and then commit with a message. I have not been able to find an equivalent in Visual Studio.

I imagine this must be possible via the Git Bash prompt but this would be inconvenient if there are many changes.

I have looked through the Git options in Visual Studio but cannot see an option that would enable this feature. I also queried the Visual Studio help documentation and followed a few of the top URLs.

Is there a process, or a built-in tool for this purpose, or perhaps a third party extension?

Comment: This is on the VS roadmap (though it has been for some time), upvote here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/git-stage-selected-portion-of-file/443834

Comment: I appreciate the pointer, I have voted for the feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has [shipped with Visual Studio 17.3](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/git-line-staging-released/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/git-stage-selected-portion-of-file/443834) is the feature working with Visual Studio 2022 version 17.2